# MySQL one to one relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to explain a little bin, I have two tables:

*English_article:*

```
id
Title
Author
Content
...
```

And I also have:

*Netherland_article:*

```
id
Title
Author
Content
English_id ( Could be null)
...
```

English_id is a foreign key to English article. I know that this is not the best way to do that, but it is a old project and I can not migrate that to a properly structure.

So, from this structure I want to get the latest english articles that are not part of the relation. I mean, the flow is.. someone write the article in english and then we want to import the articles that are not part of the relation to Netherland table. How can I get the latest articles from the english table that are already not added.

In a example.

**English table:**

```
ID  TITLE      CONTENT    
1   article1   blablablabla 
2   article2   blablablabla 
3   article3   blablablabla 
4   article4   blablablabla 
5   article5   blablablabla 
6   article6   blablablabla 
7   article7   blablablabla
```

**Netherland Table:**

```
ID  TITLE    CONTENT        ENGLISH_ID
1   article1 blablablabla   5
2   article1 blablablabla   7
```

My goal is try to get the articles 1,2,3,4 and 6 with one query.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I will be more careful the next time. Thank you for you advice.

Comment: Maybe this *is* next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why will the below not help.

```
select * from english_articles
where id not in (select english_id from netherlands_article)
```

It will give the articles which dont have a mapping

Comment: It''s working but is really slow, How can I limit to check only the latest 100 english articles? I mean from the latest 100 english articles (order by id for example) which are not part of the relation.

Comment: @CastorDuran do you have fields for finding the latest articles ? like a field like "creation_date" of the record. Based on that, you can fetch only 100 rows.

Comment: Yes I have a created_date field but I can not add a limit inside a IN clause ( i am using MYSQL 5.5).

My goal is make this query only for the last 100 articles (in english and in netherland). 

select * from english_articles
where id not in (select english_id from netherlands_article limit 100) limit 100;

But it doesn't work

Comment: you might want to put limit only in the outer query and not in the sub query. after all, you only want the 100 english articles, which satisfy your condition that, there should be no corresponding Dutch article. `select * from english_articles where id not in (select english_id from netherlands_article) limit 100;`

Comment: Yes it works but it is really slow (30 seconds), and I only want to check in the latest 100 articles in each table. Is there any solution?

Comment: do you have an Index on `id` in english_articles table ? you can try rebuilding the index. how many total records are there in the table ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM english
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT english_id FROM netherland)
```

Comment: Consider adding the insert as well to show the whole query to select the required rows and to insert them into the table (just had this come up in a answer for review for deletion by SO)